# Problem in angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect

In angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy (ARPES), the energy $E_k$ and angle $\theta$ to the normal of a photoelectron is measured and used to find the band structure. The electron momentum parallel to the surface is conserved and given by $$k_{\parallel}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\sqrt{2m_eE_k}\sin(\theta).$$ However, the perpendicular component is not conserved and is usually written as $$k_{\perp}=\frac{1}{\hbar}\sqrt{2m_e(E_k\cos^2(\theta)+V_0)}.$$
Wikipedia says that $-V_0$ is the energy at the bottom of an assumed parabolic, free-electron-like final state. Does this mean that the band is assumed to be of this form? If so, isn't ARPES pointless if we assume the band shape in the first place, and isn't it a bad approximation given that real bands have an effective mass different from free electrons? Also, why is $V_0$ not related to the work function and Fermi energy?